# Complete Linux Folder Separation

Tags: linux, debian, acl

Hello fellow Linux users. I'm running Debian 11. I am running an nginx web server with multiple sites. Each site's root directory is owned by a particular user. **My goal is to completely make one user's web files not visible to another user**. `user1` owns `/var/www/site1` and `user2` owns `/var/www/site2`. It's OK that `user1` can see that the folder `site2` exists, but I don't want him to be able to `ls` the directory or access any files inside. *I want the other users' directories to be completely opaque.*

I first changed the permissions of the directory to `750`, but then the web server user `www-data` couldn't access the folder's contents. Then I set up ACLs to allow `www-data` read access.

My (crazy) steps that work:

```
chown -R user1: .
find . -type f -exec chmod 640 {} +
find . -type d -exec chmod 2750 {} +
setfacl -Rdm u::rwx,g::rx,o::0,u:www-data:rx .   # this didn't set up ACLs for individual files, hence the next line
find . -type f -exec setfacl -m u::rw,g::r,o::0,u:www-data:r {} +
```

**Question**: Is there an easier way to allow the web server to access the folder's contents, while restricting other users? Or are there easier steps than what I took?

(Note: I tried adding the user `www-data` to the `user1` group and vice-versa. Even though the group has read permission and nginx is running as `user www-data www-data;`, nginx still couldn't access the folder's contents...)

Comment: If `www-data` can read other directories, any user which can make a script (e.g. PHP) run by www-data can do the same. So either you make reverse proxies or (suPHP) so that each uses execute with own username, else you are doing nothing useful to hide configuration files.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks for your reply. Each user's PHP-FPM process runs as their username and group, i.e. they each have their own pool running as their user. I don't think there's any way they could execute a script as another user. Am I wrong?

Comment: `chmod 700 /var/www/site*` should do the trick until and unless someone manages to exploit a privilege escalation vuln in your web server settings.